# Html 5 canvas javascript collision detection x/y correction

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection, createjs

I'm creating a way to move boxes around on a surface (example pallet/shelf/floor ) using canvas.

I have the following layout of boxes to start of with.

```
[{"a":0,"b":0,"c":500,"d":400},
 {"a":0,"b":400,"c":500,"d":800},
 {"a":500,"b":0,"c":1000,"d":400},
 {"a":500,"b":400,"c":1000,"d":800}]
```

Surface is

```
1200 x 800mm pal {palL : 1200 , palW : 800}

a = x , b = y , c = x+box length , d = y+box length
```

I'm using easlejs not that it should matter but the drag event returns x and y changes

so `{x: -100, y: 50}`

The Box collision detection seems to be working but when I try and alter the movedx and y distences to place it back onto the boundary of the box it hit, everything falls apart. This is the first time I've ever done this type of calculation before (as im sure you can tell from the code below) any help I can get will be appreciated.

```
boxshape.on("pressmove", function (evt) {
                    var originalx = this.x;
                    var originaly = this.y;
                    var movedX = Math.floor(evt.stageX + this.offset.x);
                    var movedY = Math.floor(evt.stageY + this.offset.y);
                    var box = this.boxcoords;
                    var newBox = {
                        a: box.a + Math.floor(movedX / fac),
                        b: box.b + Math.floor(movedY / fac),
                        c: box.c + Math.floor(movedX / fac),
                        d: box.d + Math.floor(movedY / fac)
                    };
                    this.newboxcoords = newBox;

                    // check collision with pallet.
                    if(newBox.c > pal.palL) {
                        var dif = (newBox.c - pal.palL)*fac;
                        movedX -= dif;
                        newBox.c = pal.palL;
                        newBox.a = newBox.c - paldata.box.l;
                    }
                    if(newBox.d > pal.palW) {
                        var dif = (newBox.d - pal.palW)*fac;
                        movedY -= dif;
                        newBox.d = pal.palW;
                        newBox.b = newBox.d - paldata.box.w;
                    }
                    if(newBox.a < 0) {
                        movedX = movedX - newBox.a*fac;
                        newBox.a = 0;
                        newBox.c = paldata.box.l;
                    }
                    if(newBox.b < 0) {
                        movedY = movedY - newBox.b*fac;
                        newBox.b = 0;
                        newBox.d = paldata.box.w;
                    }
                    // CODE ABOVE WORKS WITH NO PROBLEMS 
                    // CODE BELOW IS THE TROUBLE ZONE
                    // check collision with other boxs
                    for(var c = 0; c < shapeArray.length; c++) {
                        otherBox = shapeArray[c].newboxcoords;

                        if (newBox.a < otherBox.c && newBox.c > otherBox.a &&
                            newBox.b < otherBox.d && newBox.d > otherBox.b && otherBox !== newBox) {

                            if(newBox.a < otherBox.c && newBox.c > otherBox.a) {

                                if(movedX < 0) {
                                    movedX = movedX - ((otherBox.c - newBox.a)* fac);
                                    newBox.a = otherBox.c;
                                    newBox.c = newBox.a + paldata.box.l;
                                }else{
                                    movedX = movedX - ((newBox.c - otherBox.a) * fac);
                                    newBox.c = otherBox.a;
                                    newBox.a = newBox.c - paldata.box.l;
                                }
                            }
                            if(newBox.b < otherBox.d && newBox.d > otherBox.b) {
                                if(movedY < 0) {
                                    movedY = movedY - ((otherBox.d - newBox.b)* fac);
                                    newBox.b = otherBox.d;
                                    newBox.d = newBox.b + paldata.box.w;
                                }else{
                                    movedY = movedY - ((newBox.d - otherBox.b) * fac);
                                    newBox.d = otherBox.b;
                                    newBox.b = newBox.d - paldata.box.w;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // CODE ABOVE IS TROUBLE ZONE
                    this.x = movedX;
                    this.y = movedY;
                    if(originalx !== this.x || originaly !== this.y) {
                        boxMoved = true;
                    }

        update = true;
                });
```

Comment: Instead of `a, b, c, d`, why don't you use `x, y, w, h`? It makes your code a heck of a lot easier to read.

Comment: i agree with you there. the server side layout generator returns the json array iv included in the post. i have not yet altered this code ( written by a previous employee ) so iv continued using a/b/c/d because thats how it was originally.

Comment: "everything falls apart" - it would be extremely helpful if you tell us what actually happens...